# Make control transparent to drag events during drag-and-drop

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, drag-and-drop

I have a `ListView` that acts as a drop target for drag and drop operations. When the list is empty, I place a `TextBlock` over top of it with a message informing users they can drag things there (both controls are contained in a single `Grid` cell to enable overlap). But... since the `TextBlock` is on top of the `ListView`, it intercepts the various events connected to drag and drop and prevents things from being dropped onto the message text itself.

I really don't want to add a drop handler to the `TextBlock`--is there any way I can simply make it "transparent" to drag and drop operations?

Something that just occurred to me while writing this which does work is to put the text below the list in the Z-order and then give the list a transparent background. But is this really the right way to achieve this? Ideally, there'd be a way to give the text one `ZIndex` for rendering, and a different one for hit testing.

Comment: Simply use the ListView's PreviewDragEnter/Drop event handlers so it gets the notification before the TextBlock does.

Comment: @HansPassant The root of the problem is that the ListView gets PreviewDragLeave when the cursor moves over the text, and the drag/drop framework I'm using handles that by setting the drag effects to none, which tells Windows not to allow dropping. I have the source code for the framework so I could change this behavior, but I'd prefer not to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set [`IsHitTestVisible`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.ishittestvisible.aspx) to  `False` for `TextBlock`.

Comment: Works. I knew there had to be something simple.